# Type 'never' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: angular, typescript

After upgrading to Angular 9 I get the following Typescript errors:

Type 'never' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)

Property 'assignableClients' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)

Below is a snippet of the code where the error is occurring:

```
    .subscribe((result) => {
        if (result) {
            const [hasPermission, client] = result;
            return observer.next(hasPermission && includes(client.assignableClients, clientCd));
        }
    });
```

I'm sure how to solve these issues. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding the following to `tsconfig`

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es5", "es6", "dom", "dom.iterable"
        ]
    }
}

Comment: Check [this](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-never-type-in-typescript) out, not sure of the relevance, but I hadn't heard of the 'never' type before...  Also, can you comment out the if statement in it's entirety and console.log result and post that?

Comment: Just a hunch, but, do you have a class/type that is named "never"? If so, post the code so we can take a look.